# Can I increase video conversion speed by adding a video card?

Tags: video, graphics-card, vlc-media-player, mp4

We are working on a project where we convert multiple live h.264 (MPEG-4 AVC) videos in real time. At the moment we are using an Intel Core i7-6700K CPU, so its clock speed is the barrier of the number of simultaneous streams.

Is it possible to increase the conversion performance by adding 1 or more video cards? If so, will it be automatically faster, or will it require a special software/method to utilize the extra hardware?  (In case it cannot be done this way, we will build another converter machine...)

Additional info: Currently we are using multiple instances of VideoLAN VLC media player. The source videos are various, the output is always the same size and type, so it's usually downscaling (1 mbps output from 10-20 mbps sources).

Comment: Why did anyone downvote my question? Is it a duplicate? At least provide a reason with the -1...

Comment: I can't explain the downvotes, but I upvoted because it seems like an interesting question. You're not asking for specific hardware recommendations re the card, so that wouldn't be a fair reason for a downvote, it seems to me.

Comment: Only if you're using a GPU-based encoder such as nvenc. But CPU based encoders such as x264 are more mature.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use h.264 ?

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya, your comment helped me to step forward in the topic.

Comment: @yoyo_fun, well, the output has to be MPEG-4 AVC.

Comment: Update: We went with the nvenc method, and it is great. GTX cards are limited to only 1 stream at a time, but newer Quadro cards can provide "unlimited" simultaneous transcodings. With low bitrate (SD video, 1 mbps) the h264_nvenc output quality is not worse than x264.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you add a good Video card and use it to encode video the speed will be MUCH MUCH faster.

You have to use the encoding type supported by your video card though. I am not sure if x.264 is supported but I tested FULL HD video encoding on a 6700k first using the processor and then using GPU based NVIDIA encoding on a GTX 1060 and the Nvidia encoding way way faster. I think more than 5 times faster.

Comment: 5 times faster encoding sounds great. But what about the output quality?

Comment: There was absolutely no visible difference.

Answer (score 0):

With GPU encoding you can improve the total time needed to encode, but GPU encoders tends to provide lower quality. This is particularly visible if you have low bitrate and high motion scenes. I would better invest in a new multi-core CPU rather than a GPU if quality matters. Besides that, how powerful the GPU is doesn't matter. What matters is the hardware encoder used.

- Currently NVidia GPUs have better hardware encoder than AMD
- 2000 and 3000 series have the same 7th gen encoder. Even the lowest card from this family will provide better results from any other more powerful card with 6th gen encoder and below.
- NVidia GTX 1660 and *some* GTX 1650 are also bundled with 7th gen encoder.

https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new